# geom_label_repel to display labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, label

I am trying to plot a graph using the geom_label_repel function to show the country label next to each line. I am not sure why, but for Sweden (orange line), the label is not showing next to the line: [image: see graph here]

Would be so happy for any tips! Thank you!

Here is the code I used so far:

````
# create label for plot
df_YouGov5$label[which(df_YouGov5$DATE2 == max(df_YouGov5$DATE2))] <- df_YouGov5$COUNTRY[which(df_YouGov5$DATE2 == max(df_YouGov5$DATE2))]

# ggplot 
ggplot(df_YouGov5, aes(x=DATE2, y=PERCENT, group=COUNTRY))+
  geom_smooth(method = "auto", se = FALSE, aes(col=COUNTRY), size = 0.71)+
  theme_light()+
  labs(col = "COUNTRY", 
       title = "% of people in each country who think the government is handling the issue of the coronavirus 'very' or 'somewhat' well",
       x = "",
       y = "", 
       caption = "Source: Imperial College London YouGov Covid 19 Behaviour Tracker")+ 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 20), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15), 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 15))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=10), label = label_number(suffix = "%"))+
  scale_color_npg()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("May-20", "Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20", "Sept-20", "Oct-20", "Nov-20", "Dec-20", 
                             "Jan-21", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Apr-21", "May-21", "Jun-21", "Jul-21", "Aug-21", "Sept-21", "Oct-21", "Nov-21", "Dec-21",
                             "Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-22"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = label), 
                   size = 6) ```
````

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: It' may be because you might be  using the absolute maximum date to put your labels and sweden doesn't extend that far. Try putting relative maximums

Comment: @Jahi Zamy, I think you are right with the maximum, I am playing around with it now to try and change it! Thank you for your support!!

Comment: sweden does not appear in the label column